# liferay 7 integration with cas using ldap

Tags: ldap, single-sign-on, cas, liferay-7

I'm newbie to liferay 7,I want to integrate liferay 7 with CAS server using ldap.

my liferay's version is 7.0.2 GA3,CAS server's version is 3.5.2 and I'm using opendj active directory.

I have installed liferay on localhost:8080,CAS server is on one of my server 
machine over ssl and ldap is on the same server machine.

I have successfully integrated CAS with ldalp that is I can able to login in CAS server from ldap users.
After this I have configured CAS authentication in liferay that is in Configuration->Instance Setting->Authentication under this CAS tab.
when I try to login im getting following url:

http://localhost:8080/?ticket=ST-36-tP25deAgea9pUfwEcf6V-cas01.example.org

Although ticket is generating,but I'm not able to access admin panel.

Please help,
Thanks in advace

Comment: Can you provide your cas liferay instance settings?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because there is a handshake error, so, when you configure your keystore you must be careful with CN name, cause you must use the domain name, not the IP, and if you don't have a DNS you could configure a host file, for example `/etc/hosts` in CentOS.